# Sudo permission issues

Tags: node.js, sudo

When running `sudo make install` I run into permission issues. This makes no sense to me as I would expect sudo to have permission to do anything.

### Example of sudo vs non sudo execution:

This is also used by node.js make but I ran it separately.

```
[tydup13@kirk node]$ stat /home/tydup13/git/node/out/Release/obj.target/deps/cares/libcares.a 
  File: ‘/home/tydup13/git/node/out/Release/obj.target/deps/cares/libcares.a’
  Size: 740904      Blocks: 1448       IO Block: 1048576 regular file
Device: 27h/39d Inode: 116264377   Links: 2
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (13993/ tydup13)   Gid: (13993/ tydup13)
Context: system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0
Access: 2014-01-30 15:31:52.473071581 -0700
Modify: 2014-01-30 15:29:08.425186992 -0700
Change: 2014-01-30 15:29:08.567191219 -0700
 Birth: -
[tydup13@kirk node]$ sudo stat /home/tydup13/git/node/out/Release/obj.target/deps/cares/libcares.a 
stat: cannot stat ‘/home/tydup13/git/node/out/Release/obj.target/deps/cares/libcares.a’: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that sudo was squashed on the computer I was using and doesn't allow sudo to cross user boundaries for security. Useful and annoying at the same time.